# How to install keras on Win10?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras

I know there are a lot of tutorials of installing keras on win. But I am faced with a weird problem and I cannot find a solution on Google.
The version of python I used is 2.7(anaconda 64bit).
When I typed 'pip install keras' in cmd, an error occurred.
[image]

It is said that no matching distribution found for tensorflow(from keras).
I googled it and one saying goes that this problem occurred when python is 32bit on windows. However, my python is 64-bit, so this saying does not hold.
I want to know how to handle this, given that I want to use theano as keras backend instead of tensorflow.

Comment: Have you tried to install TensorFlow first? Follow this: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia you mean I must install tensorflow before install keras? but I only want to use theano as my backend.

Comment: With the newest version TensorFlow is the default backend. In fact, pip is trying to install it without success according to your error.

Comment: Finally, I decide to install it on Linux. Windows ni shi wo ba ba...

Comment: Theano is a bitch to install on Windows and I don't think you can just `pip install Theano` on windows the same way you can on Linux and OSX. Which, of course, breaks pip installs for anything that requires Theano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that TensorFlow on Windows only support Python 3.5.X.

You should try installing anaconda3.

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

Answer (score 0):

using commad pip install -v -v -v keras may offer you more information about this
and I find this commad may download Keras tar file in site https://pypi.python.org/simple/keras/
and after download file, it will check the requires.txt in Keras.egg-info 
then i find in Keras 2.0.0 it require tensorflow instead of theano in this version, otherwise you may fail to install
so the solution is, download the other keras in site which requires theano not tensorflow, and unpack it, then cd its directory, and use python setup.py install to install this version of keras